# Android command list

Tags: android

I have many questions about Android command. I do not know where I should start But, anyway, I have put all question related Android commands. Here ;

- Is subset of Linux commands come in Android by default ? Or, Are we installing something ?
- In system/bin, there are lots of commands. Where can I find their meaning ? I have tried `man`, but `man` is not built in.
- Can I start and stop application via `start` and `stop` command ?
- Why cannot I run the reboot from  terminal emulator ? The error `permission is denied`.

NOTE : feel free to reedit the question, if you see meaningless part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is subset of Linux commands come in Android by default ? Or, Are we installing something ?

A subset exists by default within the system. Things like ls, cd, mkdir, cat etc... are present. You can gain access to a wider range by installing Busy Box on a rooted device, as stated by Zac.

> In system/bin, there are lots of commands. Where can I find their meaning ? I have tried man, but man is not built in.

[The ADB Page](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) is a good place to start. That covers many of the basic ADB and shell commands. It states near the bottom:

"For a complete list of commands and programs, start an emulator instance and use the `adb -help` command."

So you can use `adb -help` on an emualator or device to see a full list of the ADB and shell commands (note I think this list will be android specific commands only, it won't include things like cd,ls and other basic unix commands).

> Can I start and stop application via start and stop command ?

No, it states on the ADB dev page:

start ........ Starts (restarts) an emulator/device instance.

stop  ........ Stops execution of an emulator/device instance.

To start an application you'll use the `am` utility iirc it will look something like `am start com.your.packagename` It's been a while though, I might have syntax wrong. The instructions are listend if you issue the `am` command by itself with no params in a shell.

> Why cannot I run the reboot from terminal emulator ? The error permission is denied.

The system prevents applications from rebooting the device unless they are signed with the same key as the OS. When you use the terminal emulator you are restricted to whatever permissions that application has declared. The reboot permission is not granted to any third party applications, so it won't work correctly from any terminals. You could probably do it if your device was rooted and you used `su` though

EDIT:

[Here is another good resource that lists more of the shell commands](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki/Android-Shell-Command-Reference)

Comment: hi, is it possible that I can **disable** 3g with Android command ?

Comment: some helpful command are available here http://www.androidcentral.com/android-201-10-basic-terminal-commands-you-should-know

Answer (score 1):

There are not many Linux commands included in android, however if you are rooted you can easily install busybox which has a large range of linux commands.

You need to have root access to reboot your device via the command line (to prevent any old app being able to do it)

Comment: where can I find their meaning and information about how I can use them ?

Comment: http://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html gives a good overview, however this is for busybox in general (not just androids version) so some commands may not be included